# why is constructor called in my WPF when binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I have a WPF application with the following XAML in my MainWindow.xaml.

I don't understand why the DxTaskList constructor is called when I make a call to `OnPropertyChanged("Sequences");`. As you see below, my tab control is bound to a Sequences list. In the related view model class, I have a Sequences property that I modify, so naturally I need to let the view know, so I make the call to the `OnPropertyChanged("Sequences")` but I'm trying to understand how WPF works.

Does the entire visual tree get rebuilt when you refresh the binding of a parent? How does that work? Please note that my app uses Prism, so I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="TaskList">
    <dx:DXTabControl x:Name="TabControl" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences}"
                     SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
        <dx:DXTabControl.View>
            <dx:TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="Bottom"/>
        </dx:DXTabControl.View>
        <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </dx:DXTabControl>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything appears to be working as it should.
If your Sequences property is an ObservableCollection it will fire NotifyPropertyChanged on any change to the size of the collection. If Sequences is not an ObservableCollection, but is some other IEnumerable then your OnPropertyChanged("Sequences") will do it.

Back to your question:
Let's assume it is not an ObservableCollection. You insert an item and then fire OnPropertyChanged("Sequences"), a new DxTaskList is created (ctor is called) and gets inserted into the visual tree.

Try calling OnPropertyChanged("Sequences") twice in a row, I bet you are only hitting the constructor after the first, and not on the second. If not, it could be because of how the DxTabControl is internally implemented.

Comment: My Sequences is an ObservableCollection, so does that mean that the DxTaskList constructor should only be called once? Or should it be called every time the list of Sequences changes?

Comment: I am not 100% on this, but yes, when the list changes the TabControl should be creating a new item and hence a new DxTaskList is created. But if you are using PRISM, if the PartCreationPolicy on DxTaskList is shared (or perhaps even not specified, e.g. the default mode) you will be given a static (singleton) instance ergo no ctor (except the first time).